# Iterating json response not working

Tags: jquery, json

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "auth/classes/", 
  async: true,
  cache: false,
  success: function(data){
    var json=eval('('+data+ ')');
```

The response that i get is

```
{
  "id":"1117",
  "name":"London"
}
{
  "id":"1118",
  "name":"New York
}
{
  "id":"1119",
  "name":"California"
}
```

I can access the first array like this `json['id']`,`json['name']`

How can I iterate through this response ?

Comment: Is it the correct JSON response? I think it should be like  [{"id":"1117","name":"London"},
 {"id":"1118","name":"New York"},
 {"id":"1119","name":"California"}]

Comment: the json you're getting is not valid, you should dump as an array of your cities.

Comment: Did you try parsing it with `JSON.parse(data)`, as that eval() seems like a horrible idea.

Comment: if i use json.parse(data) whats the alternative for json[id] ? as thats how i use at the moment ?Thanks

Comment: @user3038421, `json.id`

Comment: try `console.log(data)` to see what it really is, I mean, type of data

Comment: {"id":"1117","name":"London"}, {"id":"1118","name":"New York"}, {"id":"1119","name":"California"}

Comment: Do you know what you are getting is valid JSON? Do you produce the response on the server side? If yes, how? Just like @Frederik.L asked, but slightly more specific, please post the exact output of `console.log("<%o>", data);` here.

Answer (score 1):

So let's focus on your success handling function here.  Specifically the `data` argument passed to it.  If the content type header on the response from the server is application/json, then jQuery is smart enough to understand that and pass a javascript object as your `data` parameter.

If you don't know what your server is passing back, I recommend you do this:

```
success: function(data){
    console.log(data); 
}
```

and then examine the object on the console (I recommend Chrome because it has an awesome debugger).  If instead of a javascript object, you're getting json as text, then the right way to parse it is:

```
var dataAsAnObject = JSON.parse(data);
// and accessing parts of the object once parsed, it depends on the object:
// you use [integer] to access arrays:
var thisIsTheThirdElementInAnArray = dataAsAnObject[3];
// you use ['string'] to access values by key in an associative array:
var thisIsTheValueOfKeyHello = dataAsAnObject['Hello'];
```

In your case, it's not clear, because what you pasted is not valid json.  But my advice is just to step through the debugger and log things to the console so you can learn more about it.

Answer (score 0):

not sure what the real question here is, and you are certainly not getting the response you wrote. maybe you are getting:

[ {"id":"1117","name":"London"},
 {"id":"1118","name":"New York"},
 {"id":"1119","name":"California"}]

an **Array**? maybe you are getting the array as part of an object? I guess that this strange result has to do with the strange use of `eval` (I didn't really get what you are trying to do with that - parse a JSON?)

but since it's probably an array you could iterate over it with the [usual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for):

```
for (var i =0, i < data.length, i++) {
  console.log(data[i].id); //etc.. do something usefull with the data
```

}

Comment: the response i get is this.. used console.log(data)

Comment: {"id":"1117","name":"London"}, {"id":"1118","name":"New York"}, {"id":"1119","name":"California"}

Comment: @user3038421 how do you console.log the data exactly? I think there is a missing step that fails you, since the strange success function doesn't console log anything

Comment: alonisser is right, you couldn't(well, shouldn't) be getting that response. It should probably be an array, like `[{"id":"1117","name":"London"}, {"id":"1118","name":"New York"}, {"id":"1119","name":"California"}]` in `data`. In which case, you can access the different values with `data[0].name`(London) or `data[2].id`(1119)

Comment: while($row = $result->fetch_array()){
 $response = array();
 $response['id'] =$row['id'];
 $response['name']= $row['name'];
 echo json_encode($response);
}

Comment: Is it because of this ? This is how i send the response from the server side (php)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, no, you can't directly filter on a json array like this. You must iterate over every json objects of the array to look for the ones that match your criterias.

For example, *given a valid json object array*, if you want to filter on the id attribute and get the first matching one, you could iterate like this:

```
function getCityById(data,ID) {
    var found=false, i=0;
    while (!found && i<data.length) {
        if (data[i].id === ID) {
            found=true;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        return data[i];
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then, you could access a specific ID like this:

```
var city = getCityById(data, 1117);
if (city != null) {
    var name = city.name; // should be "London"
}
```